# Mobile data times out on Sony Xperia X5 Compact

Tags: sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia X5 Compact (Android 6.0.1) which suddenly about two weeks ago lost the ability to transmit data over the mobile network. All connections just time out. The behaviour is the same in all the apps i have tried so far.

- The reception is fine and it connects to 4g networks
- There are no issues with calling
- There are no issues with WIFI
- The balance on the prepaid card is 1gb.

Unfortunatly I have a cheap prepaid phone operator that gives extremely limited customer service and have just bought a six month charge.

I'm coming to whits ends, this is what I have tried so far:

- reset the network settings
- changing to a new sim card (which works fine in another phone)
- toggling on and off anything network related
- re-download the APN settings and ensured they match the operators specs
- total factory reset

Have I missed something here or is this a hardware issue?

Comment: Tried the SIM on another phone?

Comment: Yes, I picked up a new SIM card today and tried it on an Iphone which worked perfectly.